# PHP - URL rewrite not working in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

i created dynamic products like mini shopping cart 
my url something like this

```
<a class="button_view" href="view.php?procode=<?php echo $obj->product_code; ?>">View</a>
```

in browser i saw this link

```
http://localhost/sd/view.php?procode=PD1001
```

i want to rewrite url and make seo friendly my htacess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +Indexes
Options         +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} hack
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !go
RewriteRule . - [F]
RewriteRule ^view.php?procode=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ view/$1/$2
</IfModule>
```

i want something like this

```
http://localhost/sd/view/sunglasses/
http://localhost/sd/view/iphone6/
http://localhost/sd/view/androidphonefx1/
```

Comment: Why not first change your HTML to `<a class="button_view" href="/sd/view/<?php echo $obj->product_code.'/'.$obj->product_name; ?>">View</a>`

Comment: thanx for reply @anubhava now what is next step i found 404 error after click this link

http://localhost/sd/view/PD1001/AndroidPhoneFX1

Comment: For next step see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your href to:

```
<a href="/sd/view/<?php echo $obj->product_code.'/'.$obj->product_name; ?>">View</a>
```

then use these rules in your `/sd/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sd/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} hack
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !go
RewriteRule . - [F]

RewriteRule ^view/([\w-]+) view.php?procode=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i got  : Object not found!  404 error on this link 

http://localhost/sd/view/PD1002/televisions

when PD1002 is product id <<
televisions is product name <<

Comment: But in question you wrote intended URI is: `/sd/view/sunglasses/` there was no prodId and prodName separately. What would be internal URI for `/sd/view/PD1002/televisions`?

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. 

current url is : http://localhost/sd/view/PD1002/televisions

Comment: I asked you a question in my previous comment. And what is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: .htaccess is in the folder files on this folde
index.php
cart.php
.htaccess


C:\xampp\htdocs\sd\

Comment: .htaccess's location is a folder named htdocs/sd
this folder is main folder in this folder 
index.php, style.css, cart.php, .htaccess

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51164/discussion-between-vivek-and-anubhava)

Comment: Sorry have to run so can't chat. Nothing wrong in rules now as I use these type of rules on production host. btw you still haven't answered my question **`What would be internal URI for /sd/view/PD1002/televisions`**

Comment: i will fetch data from view.php page by product code : PD1001

Comment: ok latest update should work. I will come back online in my evening time to check again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this sounds familiar to me.

Actually you have to make mod_rewrite to work on another direction.

You actually want to receive links like this:

```
http://yourhost/sd/view/sunglasses/{code}
http://yourhost/sd/view/iphone6/{code}
```

And you want to rewrite those internally to something like this:

```
http://yourhost/sd/view.php?procode={code}
```

So in that case your RewriteRule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^view/sd/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ view?procode=$1
```

Where you just need to grab your code from the url to pass to the rewritten procode param.

You can also grab both or just the item name and try to match the item just through the name in your system (what would be harder and maybe quite tricky).

Comment: Probably your rewrite base should be /sd and not /

Comment: yes typing mistake in / but this code notwork without / or with /



http://localhost/sd/view/PD1002/televisions